# Apple Vision Pro Pair With Xcode unknown error occurred

Tags: xcode, vision-pro

I would like to run a debug program on an actual Apple Vision Pro device, but my Xcode is unable to pair with the real device and it's displaying a generic error message as follow：

[image: error detail]

When AVP close Remote tab, Xcode device was shown as follow:

[image: error detail 2]

macOS version: 14.3.1

Xcode version: 15.2 (15C500b)

visionOS version: 1.0 (21N301) SDK + visionOS 1.0 (21N305) Simulator (Installed)

PS: The first time Apple Vision Pro was paired with my Mac, it worked, but then I manually unpaired my Vision Pro device in Xcode's device list, then it never worked.

1. Try reboot AVP and Mac
2. Try change Apple ID
3. Try update Xcode version to 15.3 and update VisionOS 1.1 beta3
4. Try another WIFI
5. Try clean Xcode cache/device ... , and reinstall Xcode

but nothing changed.

Comment: Clicking on “Screen Mirroring” first on your Mac. I’ve had issues connecting a couple of times and starting mirroring from Mac usually fixes it but I did buy the developer strap.

Comment: I tried, it did't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved. The solution: Reset the network configuration on the Mac.

- cd to /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
- remove all .plist file except com.apple.Boot.plist
- reboot mac
- reconnect your Apple Vision Pro and Mac